# Can anyone explain me what is going on here in this bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

for this UNIX shell script, i got to use a meaningful example input to
explain the purpose and any possible output.

```
str=””
for word in $*
do
    if [$word == Tokyo]
    then
        str = “Capital Japan $str”
    else
        str = “$word $str”
    fi
done

echo str;
```

Comment: The script has ~9 bugs that will prevent it from doing anything useful. Are you asking "Why does it fail?" or "What was it supposed to do?"

Comment: To be honest, this is too simple to be asking for help with on SO! Did you try it? Experiment with it? At most, maybe `$*` isn’t obvious....so look it up! Maybe [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129077).

Comment: I tried running it.. It justs prints str

Comment: The author's intention was undoubtedly to let you run `./myscript Sydney Tokyo Reykjavik` and it would output `Sydney Capital Japan Reykjavik`, but there's a pile of errors that stand in the way of that (the author should probably have used [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net)

Comment: The script likely does not run. The quotes look wrong to me. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your script has the following problems:

- need space after `[` since it is a *command*. Also you need a space before `]`
- it is a [good practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86800/quote-a-variable-in-shell-script-if-statement) to quote both sides of the comparison in the if statement
- need to use double quotes instead of the right double quotation mark you're currently using
- need to remove spaces around `=` when assigning to a variable
- no need to initialize `str`
- the assignment `str="$word $str"` is unclear

After these corrections the script becomes:

```
# scipt.sh
for word in $*
do
    if [ "$word" == "Tokyo" ]
    then
        str="Capital Japan $str"
        echo "$str"
    else
        str="$word"
        echo "$str"
    fi
done
```

testing the script from the shell:

```
$ bash script.sh some Tokyo word
some
Capital Japan Tokyo
word
```

Comment: +1 for clear answer, but do you really need quotes around Tokyo? it is single word no special characters and such should be fine. `$word` on the other hand should be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

All right first things first your code has errors:

First error:

```
if [$word == Tokyo]
```

should be:

```
if [ "$word" == Tokyo ]
```

Space after `[` and before `]`, and quotes around "$word" to prevent word splitting

Then next:

```
str = “Capital Japan $str”
```

should be:

```
str="Capital Japan $str"
```

Notice that there is no space between `str`, equal sign and `"Capital Japan $str"`. The same problem exists on line 8. 
Also do you notice different quotes. These are double quotes that you should use. This is the case in first line of your code as well as on line 8.

And the end, to print out variable `str` you put:

```
echo $str
```

Although I do recommend using quotes. Like following

```
echo "$str"
```

This last error is causing your script to print `str` and not string named `str`